# Thunderbird-Trunk not installable in 10.04 due to unmet dependencies

Tags: 10.04, ppa, thunderbird

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

When I try to install thunderbird-trunk from the Ubuntu Mozilla Daily PPA, I get:

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> thunderbird-trunk: Depends: libindicate5 but it is not installable
>
> > ```
> >                 Depends: libdbusmenu-gtk4 but it is not installable or
> >                           libdbusmenu-gtk3 but it is not installable
> > ```
> >
> > E: Broken packages

This is very strange as I installed it last week and it worked fine.

Comment: did you try installing `libdbusmenu-gtk#` (either 3 or 4) to see why they cannot be installed?

Comment: @The Evil Phoenix, Yes, but it says that they're not available because they have no installation candidates.